# What are the "frustrated rotations" of molecules?

Tags: optics, rotation, molecules, photonics

**What are the frustrated rotation of molecules and how is this any different from the normal rotation of molecules?**

This question originated from reading: [A promising diagnostic method: Terahertz pulsed imaging and spectroscopy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3080051/) where it is stated:

"*(...)frustrated
rotations and collective modes cause polar liquids (such
as water) to absorb at THz frequencies.*"

I am trying to understand how these rotations can cause such polarisations, but first I must understand the concept of frustrated rotation.